# testing cli command with click options python

Tags: python, testing, click

Hi I have this function that I'm trying to test. In cli.py i have

```
import myfunction
import click
@click.command(name="run")
@click.option("--param", required=True, type=int)
@click.option("--plot", required=False, default=False)
def run(param, plot):
    myfunction(param, plot)
```

In my test_cli.py

from click.testing import CliRunner
from cli import run

```
def test_cli():
    kwargs = {"int": 5, "plot": False}
    runner = CliRunner()
    result = runner.invoke(run, args=kwargs)
    assert resutlts.output == ""
```

I get the following error: Missing option --param

Comment: with your edit away from `--int` your test code has got out of sync (should use `param` not `int`).  And there's a typo resultlts -> results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CliRunner.invoke` takes a list of *command line parameters*, not function parameters.

Specifically you need to call it like this:

```py
runner.invoke(run, args=["--param", "5"])
runner.invoke(run, "--param 5")
```

for multiple arguments you can use either pattern:

```py
runner.invoke(run, args=["--param", "5", "6"])
runner.invoke(run, args="--param 5 6")
```

### References

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/testing/

Comment: thanks for your answer, what if my param is a list something like this @click.option("--param", required=True, type=(iint, float)) how can I pass the parameter. I trieed ['--param', "5 2"] and ["--param", (5, 3)] but i did not work it shows : param options requires 2 arguments

Comment: how would you pass it on the command line?

Comment: by typing run --param 5 2            https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/options/#tuples-as-multi-value-options

Comment: see latest update

Comment: Thanks yes it works

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it works ;)